# Producing XXX(+/- YYY) format in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I have a class that requires we format uncertainties as X.XX(+/-0.YY).

So far, I can get `siunitx` to produce uncertainties X.XX(0.YY); however, I do not see a setting in the [manual](https://www.dpg-physik.de/dpg/gliederung/junge/rg/wuerzburg/Archiv/WS%202011-12/LaTeX/siunitx.pdf) to add the plus-minus sign.

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the `output-open-uncertainty`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{output-open-uncertainty = {(\pm}}
\begin{document}

\num{9.99(9)}

\end{document}
```